# Disable bounce scrolling for WKWebview in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview, macos-sierra

Trying to disable bounce scrolling for WKWebview in macOS,
but WKWebview in macOS has no "scrollView"

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame)
print(webView.scrollView)
```

Comment: Are you sure? This [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview) says that WKWebView has a scrollView for macOS 10.10+

Comment: @BenjaminLowry Sure, I ⌘Click in "WKWebView" and there is no such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One really weird thing about this that you may or may not have noticed is that in the WKWebView class, there is a description of the scrollView that is theoretically "supposed" to be in the class, but the scrollView is not there. This can be seen in the photo below:

[image: macOS WKWebView]

I would say that it could be a weird procedure of Apple's, but see in the iOS class, the same description is present but with an actual scrollView this time:

[image]

Unless I am missing something major here, this would likely mean one of two things:

1. There should be a scrollView but there isn't (i.e. it was accidentally deleted by Apple???)
2. The scrollView was removed from the macOS WKWebView, but the description was accidentally left in the class?

Either way this is a very weird finding.

You might want to consider doing some further research on this, and perhaps [filing a Swift bug report](https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs).

**EDIT:**

It was pointed out to me that this scroll view is in-fact a iOS only property, and the unnecessary comment is the bug.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Swift language and this isn't a Swift bug.

Comment: @Willeke Could you elaborate? Why would there be a description for a missing object?

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the header. Everything is ok in Objective-C and OS X 10.10. The property `scrollView` is surrounded by `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE`. The unavailability of `scrollView` on OS X is not a bug in Swift.

Comment: @Willeke okay thanks for that, I'll update my answer then

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this? Is there no way to access the underlying `NSScrollView` of a `WKWebView` (if it even has one)?

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling can be disabled by overriding the WKWebView class:

```
class NoScrollWebView: WKWebView {
    override func scrollWheel(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: theEvent)
        return
    }
}
```

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62746859/9519322

Comment: This does not remove the scroll bars on the bottom and the right side of the webView, it only disables the scroll wheel.  A user can still grab the scroll bars and drag them.

Comment: Even the webView.enclosingScrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = false and webView.enclosingScrollView.hasVerticalScroller = false do not turn off the scroll bars.  It's crazy that Apple has not fixed this for macOS.

Comment: `enclosingScrollView` is something different, it gives you the closest parent NSScrollView which contains the WKWebView, not the scrollview used by WKWebView itself.