# Control scroll elasticity in WKWebKit for macOS

Tags: cocoa, webkit, wkwebview, appkit

I want to disable the horizontal scroll elasticity of an NKWebView instance in my app for macOS.

I know we can control elasticity of an NSScrollView with `verticalScrollElasticity` or `horizontalScrollElasticity` properties. But it seems to be impossible to obtain scrollView from new WKWebView on macOS, although WKWebView for iOS has a `scrollView` property that holds UIScrollView. I also cannot find a proper property in WKWebView to control it.

I found a Q&A: [Disable rubber-band scrolling for webview in lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020842/) in SO for the old WebView. But it doesn't work anymore with a new WKWebView since new WKWebView doesn't have a `mainFrame` property.

Comment: There's a similar question with an interesting response at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929552/disable-bounce-scrolling-for-wkwebview-in-macos

Answer (score 0):

This helped me for vertical case (at html/css level): https://stackoverflow.com/a/28411556/307093

I think you should try overflow-x css property. In case you do not control what the page displays you can execute javascript from Objective-C/Swift in the page after it is loaded, which will change the body page attributes, like `document.body.style.overflowX = 'hidden'`, probably you will need to specify `document.body.style.width` to something meaningful/concrete too.